# Replacing shapes by colour in Google Slides & Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-slides-api

I am attempting to replace shapes color in a Google Slide presentation, using Google Apps Script.

```
function changeColors() {
  const objectId = "#an-id#";  // Please set the object ID.

  const slides = SlidesApp.openById(objectId).getSlides();
  slides.forEach(loopSlides);
  
}

function loopSlides(slide){

  var shapes = slide.getShapes();
  if (shapes.length > 0) {
    shapes.forEach(myFunction);
  }
}

function myFunction(shape) {
  try{
    var st = shape.getShapeType();
  if (st != SlidesApp.ShapeType["RECTANGLE"] && 
      st != SlidesApp.ShapeType["ROUND_RECTANGLE"] &&
      st != SlidesApp.ShapeType["UNSUPPORTED"]){
          Logger.log("Not a box!!");
          Logger.log(st);
          Logger.log(shape.getText());
        return;
      }
  }
  catch(err) {
    Logger.log("Not a Shape!!");
   return; // not a shape!
}
  var hexColor = shape.getFill().getSolidFill();
  Logger.log(hexColor);
  switch (hexColor){
    case "#f16727ff": // Computer Science
      shape.getFill().setSolidFill("#413c73ff");
    case "#0b9faeff": // Information technology
      shape.getFill().setSolidFill("#d90368ff");
    case "#d71b55ff": // Digital Literacy
      shape.getFill().setSolidFill("#aa968aff");    
      }

}
```

The above code will never run the replacement code (Basically it will never reach the  `Logger.log(hexColor);` instruction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I run your code it reaches `Logger.log(hexColor);`.
The issue in your code is that your `hexColor` variable is actually a [SolidFill](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/solid-fill) object since you used [getSolidFill()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/fill#getSolidFill()).

If you want to get the RGB hexstring of the current shape, You need to first check if the [ColorType](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/color-type.html) is `RGB` using [getColorType()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/color#getColorType()). Then use [asRgbColor()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/color#asRgbColor()) to get the [RgbColor](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/rgb-color.html) object. Lastly, use [asHexString()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/rgb-color.html#ashexstring) to get the rgb color hex string.

### Sample Code:

```
function myFunction(shape) {
  try{
    var st = shape.getShapeType();
    if (st != SlidesApp.ShapeType["RECTANGLE"] && 
        st != SlidesApp.ShapeType["ROUND_RECTANGLE"] &&
        st != SlidesApp.ShapeType["UNSUPPORTED"]){
        Logger.log("Not a box!!");
        Logger.log(st);
        Logger.log(shape.getText());
        return;
    }
  }
  catch(err) {
    Logger.log("Not a Shape!!");
    return; // not a shape!
  }
  var colorType = shape.getFill().getSolidFill().getColor().getColorType();
  if(colorType != SlidesApp.ColorType.RGB ){
    Logger.log("TYPE: "+colorType);
    Logger.log("ColorType not RGB");
    return;
  }
  var hexColor = shape.getFill().getSolidFill().getColor().asRgbColor().asHexString().toLowerCase();
  Logger.log(hexColor);
  switch (hexColor){
    case "#f16727": // Computer Science
      shape.getFill().setSolidFill("#413c73");
      break;
    case "#0b9fae": // Information technology
      shape.getFill().setSolidFill("#d90368");
      break;
    case "#d71b55": // Digital Literacy
      shape.getFill().setSolidFill("#aa968a");  
      break; 
  }
  
}
```

### Sample Output:

[image]

### Note:

- I used [String.toLowerCase()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase) to change the rgb hex string into lowercase for your `switch` statement
- Your rgb hex strings is incorrect. (I removed trailing `ff`). RGB hex string should only consist of 6 characters.
- Your switch cases has missing `break` for each cases. If you don't include a `break` the shape color will always be set to the last solid fill setting which is `#aa968a`